# The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn hooks and the `useState` method has made me confused. I am assigning an initial value to a state in the form of an array. The set method in `useState` is not working for me, both with and without the spread syntax.

I have made an API on another PC that I am calling and fetching the data which I want to set into the state.

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" defer>
// import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const { useState, useEffect } = React; // web-browser variant

const StateSelector = () => {
  const initialValue = [
    {
      category: "",
      photo: "",
      description: "",
      id: 0,
      name: "",
      rating: 0
    }
  ];

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      try {
        // const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.164:5000/movies/display");
        // const json = await response.json();
        // const result = json.data.result;
        const result = [
          {
            category: "cat1",
            description: "desc1",
            id: "1546514491119",
            name: "randomname2",
            photo: null,
            rating: "3"
          },
          {
            category: "cat2",
            description: "desc1",
            id: "1546837819818",
            name: "randomname1",
            rating: "5"
          }
        ];
        console.log("result =", result);
        setMovies(result);
        console.log("movies =", movies);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return <p>hello</p>;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StateSelector />, rootElement);
</script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Neither `setMovies(result)` nor `setMovies(...result)` works.

I expect the `result` variable to be pushed into the `movies` array.

Comment: Are you able to see the changes moving `console.log("movies =", movies);` outsite the `useEffect` hook?

Answer (score 936, accepted):

Much [like `.setState()` in class components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/1048572) created by extending `React.Component` or `React.PureComponent`, the state update using the updater provided by `useState` hook is also asynchronous, and will not be reflected immediately.

**Also, the main issue here is not just the asynchronous nature but the fact that state values are used by functions based on their current closures, and state updates will reflect in the next re-render by which the existing closures are not affected, but new ones are created**. Now in the current state, the values within hooks are obtained by existing closures, and when a re-render happens, the closures are updated based on whether the function is recreated again or not.

Even if you add a `setTimeout` the function, though the timeout will run after some time by which the re-render would have happened, the `setTimeout` will still use the value from its previous closure and not the updated one.

```
setMovies(result);
console.log(movies) // movies here will not be updated
```

If you want to perform an action on state update, you need to use the `useEffect` hook, much like using `componentDidUpdate` in class components since the setter returned by `useState` doesn't have a callback pattern

```
useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of movies
}, [movies]);
```

As far as the syntax to update state is concerned, `setMovies(result)` will replace the previous `movies` value in the state with those available from the async request.

However, if you want to merge the response with the previously existing values, you must use the callback syntax of state updation along with the correct use of spread syntax like

```
setMovies(prevMovies => ([...prevMovies, ...result]));
```

Comment: Hi, what about calling useState inside a form submit handler ?  I am working on validating a complex form, and I call inside submitHandler useState hooks and unfortunately changes are not immediate !

Comment: `useEffect` might not be the best solution though, since it doesn't support asynchronous calls. So, if we would like to make some asynchronous validation on `movies` state change, we have no control over it.

Comment: please note that while the advice is very good, the explanation of the cause can be improved - nothing to do with the fact whether or not `the updater provided by useState hook`  is asynchronous, unlike `this.state` that could have been mutated if `this.setState` was synchronous, the Closure around `const movies` would remain the same even if `useState` provided a synchronous function - see the example in my answer

Comment: `setMovies(prevMovies => ([...prevMovies, ...result]));` worked for me

Comment: It is logging the wrong result because you are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) not because the setter is asynchronous. If async was the problem then you could log after a timeout, but you could set a timeout for an hour and still log the wrong result because async isn't what is causing the problem.

Comment: @HMR I understand what you are saying. Maybe i didn't explain it properly in my post. I did write that the value will be updated only in the next render. I will update my psot

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hey, I use the spread way to merge prev with a new response but it does not work for me, here's a main [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720438/how-to-use-hooks-in-correct-way?noredirect=1#comment112700130_63720669), can you please check it?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri What if it's not an object of values. just single value

Comment: `const [timeSlotList, setTimeSlotList] = useState("");`

This Working for me ....
`
`setTimeSlotList(() => [...timeSlotTime]); `

Comment: @da45 I found cloning the previous state in the setState hook fixed this. Like the above example.

Comment: So what do you do if you need a change to be immediate? Like for example, when I click the Submit button, I need to immediately show a spinner, rather than wait for setLoading and then check loading on render.

Comment: @geneb. the change between states won't be slow. It in fact won't even be visible to the naked eye.

Comment: There's an easy way to do this in a form submit handler (or any event handler) https://stackoverflow.com/a/70405577/5823517 without `useEffect`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  What if I have to use the updated data soon after i  setState in functional component. eg.   fetch(url)
                    .then(data => data.json())                                 
                    .then(res => {                                 
                           setCityKey(res.Key);                                                
                           callXYZ(city) })         //<--here, i am getting null for 'city' FYI  i've also tried using useEffect as told            
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log('err', err))

Comment: Am I the only one frustrated with these frameworks trying to "simplify" life by adding so much more complex, non-intuitive workarounds?
I learnt so much JavaScript, and now if I am creating a Set using useState, I need to somehow de-structure the Set, find the item to delete, and return a new Set with that array. What was the point of having Set then? And now updating a value using useState is not synchronous. I am spending most of my time writing workarounds for these "simple" frameworks.

Comment: This only worked for me after I added a condiitonal like so,  {movies.length > 0 ? <MovieList movies={movies} /> :  "No Movie(s) found"}. The state was just not triggering a render otherwise

Comment: This is helpful，not work like java.

Comment: I finally ended using let variable to achieve the change I wanted to see.

Answer (score 531):

<sub>*Additional details to the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/1176601):*</sub>

While React's `setState` *is* asynchronous (both classes and hooks), and it's tempting to use that fact to explain the observed behavior, it is not the ***reason why*** it happens.

TLDR: The reason is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) scope around an immutable `const` value.

---

#### *Solutions:*

- read the value in render function (not inside nested functions):

  ```
    useEffect(() => { setMovies(result) }, [])
    console.log(movies)
  ```
- add the variable into dependencies (and use the [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) eslint rule):

  ```
    useEffect(() => { setMovies(result) }, [])
    useEffect(() => { console.log(movies) }, [movies])
  ```
- use a temporary variable:

  ```
    useEffect(() => {
      const newMovies = result
      console.log(newMovies)
      setMovies(newMovies)
    }, [])
  ```
- use a mutable reference (if we don't need a state and only want to remember the value - updating a ref doesn't trigger re-render):

  ```
    const moviesRef = useRef(initialValue)
    useEffect(() => {
      moviesRef.current = result
      console.log(moviesRef.current)
    }, [])
  ```

---

#### *Explanation why it happens:*

If async was the only reason, it would be possible to `await setState()`.

However, both `props` and `state` are [assumed to be unchanging during 1 render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state).

> Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.

With hooks, this assumption is enhanced by using **constant values** with the `const` keyword:

```
const [state, setState] = useState('initial')
```

The value might be different between 2 renders, but remains a constant inside the render itself and inside any [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (functions that live longer even after render is finished, e.g. `useEffect`, event handlers, inside any Promise or  setTimeout).

Consider following fake, but **synchronous**, React-like implementation:

```js
// sync implementation:

let internalState
let renderAgain

const setState = (updateFn) => {
  internalState = updateFn(internalState)
  renderAgain()
}

const useState = (defaultState) => {
  if (!internalState) {
    internalState = defaultState
  }
  return [internalState, setState]
}

const render = (component, node) => {
  const {html, handleClick} = component()
  node.innerHTML = html
  renderAgain = () => render(component, node)
  return handleClick
}

// test:

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [x, setX] = useState(1)
  console.log('in render:', x) // ✅
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    setX(current => current + 1)
    console.log('in handler/effect/Promise/setTimeout:', x) // ❌ NOT updated
  }
  
  return {
    html: `<button>${x}</button>`,
    handleClick
  }
}

const triggerClick = render(MyComponent, document.getElementById('root'))
triggerClick()
triggerClick()
triggerClick()
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @AlJoslin at a first glance, that seems like a separate problem, even if it might be caused by closure scope. If you have a concrete question, please create a new stackoverflow question with code example and all...

Comment: actually I just finished a rewrite with useReducer, following @kentcdobs article (ref below) which really gave me a solid result that suffers not one bit from these closure problems.  (ref: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

Comment: for some reason solution 2 is not working.. I get the callback, but the value is still empty. `useEffect(() => { console.log(movies) }, [movies])` this prints nothing ..

Comment: @ACV Solution 2 works fine for the original question. If you need to solve a different problem, YMMW, but I am still 100% sure that the quoted code works as documented and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: All of these solutions require the use of useEffect. My problem is that my "movies" equivalent is an object I get from a Context provider and can be changed by many other components. I don't want to run the effect every time it's changed because my effect isn't setMovies - it's a different function I need to call only when a particular change is made to movies - a change I'm not seeing when needed because of a stale context.

Comment: excelent answer

Comment: @MattFrei useEffect was only used to illustrate that setting the state happens after a render and the state value was remembered from the previous render, it wasn't meant as an advice to actually call setState from useEffect... the rest of the explanation should apply even for useState in a Context provider, but feel free to point me to a new SO question if additional deep dive would be useful

Comment: Yes! That's what I see from source code, the `seState` is behavior LIKE async, but IS sync exactly.

Comment: "_it wasn't meant as an advice to actually call `setState` from `useEffect`..._" I'm sorry, I'm missing how this answers the OP then. That does seem to be the solution from the "previous answer" and this one, though it also seems to be anti-pattern -- you're using a mechanism for achieving side effects to change state. That is/n't antipattern & why?

Comment: both answers address the implied question from the OP: *Why do I see the previous value of state after I called `setState` from **wherever**?* Feel free to use whatever pattern as explained in https://beta.reactjs.org/ or any library that might be useful in your project, I am not telling you what you should/n't do, just why the OP didn't work.

Comment: FTR setting state from inside a Promise chain started from `useEffect` or from somewhere else in context / parent / library / callback / stream / action creator / saga / store / init / SSR magic / wherever else, they all work the same in regads to `setState` vs `the state value inside one render`.

Answer (score 29):

I know that there are already very good answers. But I want to give another idea how to solve the same issue, and access the latest 'movie' state, using my module [react-useStateRef](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref) it has 11,000+ weekly downloads.

As you understand by using React state you can render the page every time the state change. But by using React ref, you can always get the latest values.

So the module `react-useStateRef` let you use state's and ref's together. It's backward compatible with `React.useState`, so you can just replace the `import` statement

```
const { useEffect } = React
import { useState } from 'react-usestateref'

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      try {

        const result = [
          {
            id: "1546514491119",
          },
        ];
        console.log("result =", result);
        setMovies(result);
        console.log("movies =", movies.current); // will give you the latest results
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

### More information:

- [react-usestsateref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref)

Answer (score 13):

React's useEffect has its own state/lifecycle. It's related to mutation of state, and it will not update the state until the effect is destroyed.

Just pass a single argument in parameters state or leave it a black array and it will work perfectly.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect");
    (async () => {
        try {
            let result = await fetch("/query/countries");
            const res = await result.json();
            let result1 = await fetch("/query/projects");
            const res1 = await result1.json();
            let result11 = await fetch("/query/regions");
            const res11 = await result11.json();
            setData({
                countries: res,
                projects: res1,
                regions: res11
            });
        } catch {}
    })(data)
}, [setData])
# or use this
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            await Promise.all([
                fetch("/query/countries").then((response) => response.json()),
                fetch("/query/projects").then((response) => response.json()),
                fetch("/query/regions").then((response) => response.json())
            ]).then(([country, project, region]) => {
                // console.log(country, project, region);
                setData({
                    countries: country,
                    projects: project,
                    regions: region
                });
            })
        } catch {
            console.log("data fetch error")
        }
    })()
}, [setData]);
```

Alternatively, you can try React.useRef() for instant change in the React hook.

```js
const movies = React.useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
movies.current='values';
console.log(movies.current)
}, [])
```

Comment: The last code example has no need for neither async nor await as you use the Promise API. That's only needed in the first

Answer (score 12):

I just finished a rewrite with useReducer, following the Kent C. Dodds article (ref below) which really gave me a solid result that suffers not one bit from these closure problems.

See: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

I condensed his readable boilerplate to my preferred level of DRYness -- reading his sandbox implementation will show you how it actually works.

```
import React from 'react'

// ref: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

const ApplicationDispatch = React.createContext()
const ApplicationContext = React.createContext()

function stateReducer(state, action) {
  if (state.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
    return { ...state, [action.type]: state[action.type] = action.newValue };
  }
  throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
}

const initialState = {
  keyCode: '',
  testCode: '',
  testMode: false,
  phoneNumber: '',
  resultCode: null,
  mobileInfo: '',
  configName: '',
  appConfig: {},
};

function DispatchProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(stateReducer, initialState);
  return (
    <ApplicationDispatch.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <ApplicationContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </ApplicationContext.Provider>
    </ApplicationDispatch.Provider>
  )
}

function useDispatchable(stateName) {
  const context = React.useContext(ApplicationContext);
  const dispatch = React.useContext(ApplicationDispatch);
  return [context[stateName], newValue => dispatch({ type: stateName, newValue })];
}

function useKeyCode() { return useDispatchable('keyCode'); }
function useTestCode() { return useDispatchable('testCode'); }
function useTestMode() { return useDispatchable('testMode'); }
function usePhoneNumber() { return useDispatchable('phoneNumber'); }
function useResultCode() { return useDispatchable('resultCode'); }
function useMobileInfo() { return useDispatchable('mobileInfo'); }
function useConfigName() { return useDispatchable('configName'); }
function useAppConfig() { return useDispatchable('appConfig'); }

export {
  DispatchProvider,
  useKeyCode,
  useTestCode,
  useTestMode,
  usePhoneNumber,
  useResultCode,
  useMobileInfo,
  useConfigName,
  useAppConfig,
}
```

With a usage similar to this:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

// https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

import { useAppConfig, useKeyCode, usePhoneNumber } from '../../ApplicationDispatchProvider';

import { ControlSet } from '../../components/control-set';
import { keypadClass } from '../../utils/style-utils';
import { MaskedEntry } from '../../components/masked-entry';
import { Messaging } from '../../components/messaging';
import { SimpleKeypad, HandleKeyPress, ALT_ID } from '../../components/simple-keypad';

export const AltIdPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [keyCode, setKeyCode] = useKeyCode();
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = usePhoneNumber();
  const [appConfig, setAppConfig] = useAppConfig();

  const keyPressed = btn => {
    const maxLen = appConfig.phoneNumberEntry.entryLen;
    const newValue = HandleKeyPress(btn, phoneNumber).slice(0, maxLen);
    setPhoneNumber(newValue);
  }

  const doSubmit = () => {
    history.push('s');
  }

  const disableBtns = phoneNumber.length < appConfig.phoneNumberEntry.entryLen;

  return (
    <Container fluid className="text-center">
      <Row>
        <Messaging {...{ msgColors: appConfig.pageColors, msgLines: appConfig.entryMsgs.altIdMsgs }} />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <MaskedEntry {...{ ...appConfig.phoneNumberEntry, entryColors: appConfig.pageColors, entryLine: phoneNumber }} />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <SimpleKeypad {...{ keyboardName: ALT_ID, themeName: appConfig.keyTheme, keyPressed, styleClass: keypadClass }} />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <ControlSet {...{ btnColors: appConfig.buttonColors, disabled: disableBtns, btns: [{ text: 'Submit', click: doSubmit }] }} />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

AltIdPage.propTypes = {};
```

Now everything persists smoothly everywhere across all my pages

Comment: I don't think this answer is particularly helpful in the context of the OP. This answer is not even using `useState()` which was central to the OP's inquiry.

Comment: Smooth solution, but not an answer to what was going on

Answer (score 12):

I too was stuck with the same problem. As other answers above have clarified the error here, which is that `useState` is asynchronous and you are trying to use the value just after `setState`. It is not updating on the `console.log()` part because of the asynchronous nature of `setState`, it lets your further code to execute, while the value updating happens on the background. Thus you are getting the previous value. When the `setState` is completed on the background it will update the value and you will have access to that value on the next render.

If anyone is interested to understand this in detail. Here is a really good Conference talk on the topic.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 12):

Most of the answers here are about how to update a state based on its previous value, but I don't understand how that relates to the question

> The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately

---

## React 18

### useState is asynchronous:

When an event that triggers a certain code, occurs, the code starts running, and when it finshes, react will check if there was a state update and if it is the case, **only then** the value of the `useState` hook is updated and this leads to a new render in which the new value is availabe.

```js
const [example,setExemple] = useState("")
//...
<button
  onClick={() => {
    const newValue = "new";
    setExample(newValue);
    console.log(example); // output "" and this is normal, because the component didn't rerenderd yet so the new value is not availabe yet
  }}
>
  Update state
</button>
```

Supposing we have a scenario where we have a state which depends on another state, for example we want to make an API call based on the new value of `example` every time it is updated and then store the data from response in another state `anotherExample`.
to achieve so we have two ways:

**1. use the value of `newValue`:**

```js
<button
  onClick={async () => {
    const newValue = "new";
    const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/${newValue}`);
    setExample(newValue);
    setAnotherExample(response.data);
  }}
>
  test
</button>
```

since you know that `example` will receive this value, you can create your logic based on it directly.

**2. trigger a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)  to run each time `example` is updated by including `example` in its dependency array:**

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    const newValue = "new";
    setExample(newValue);
  }}
>
  test
</button>
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
 async function test(){
  const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/${example}`);
  setAnotherExample(response.data);
 } 
 test();
}, [example])
```

so when `example` is updated with the event function the component rerenders, **we are now in a new different render** that once finished, `useEffect` will run **because the value of `example` is different from what is was during the last render**, and since it is a new different render, the new value of `example` useState hook is available here.

**Note:** the `useEffect` hook will run anyway during the first mount.

### Which approach better?

- while the first method will make all the work in one render  **(a better approach)** "React groups multiple state updates into a single re-render for better performance" the second method will do it in two renders, the first when `example` is updated and the second when `anotherExample` is updated from inside `useEffect`
- since the component only rerenders when the new value of a `useState` hook is different from the old one, so when `newValue` is equal to `example` the component will not rerender so the `useEffect` will not run and `anotherExample` will not be updated  **(a better approach)**, however in the first method the API is called anyway and we don't want to do that if there is no need also if this happens `anotherExample` will be updated (`anotherExample` will receive the same data it already contains because it is the same REQUEST since `newValue` is equal to `example`) but if the response in an object or an array then, `Object.is` method (that the `useState` hook utilizezs), cannot detect if the new value is equal to the previous one, therefore, the component will rerender

### Conclusion:

As it is mentioned above, each one has its advantage, so it depends on the use case.

**the second method is more recommended**, however the first can be more performant in some cases, for example when you are sure the code will only run when `newValue` gets a new value using `onChange`, or maybe when you want to use some other local variables that you will no longer have access to from inside useEffect

Comment: The `useState` was always asynchronous since the first day, it's not related to ReactJs 18 version.

Comment: I didnt say it is a new feature in React 18.

Comment: So why you mentioned the Reactjs version? it confused me

Comment: because this answer is posted when React 18 is the last released version, maybe later it won't be valid, who knows

Answer (score 11):

The closure is not the only reason.

Based on the source code of `useState` (simplified below). Seems to me the value is never assigned right away.

What happens is that an update action is queued when you invoke `setValue`. And after the schedule kicks in and only when you get to the next render, these update action then is applied to that state.

Which means even we don't have closure issue, react version of `useState` is not going to give you the new value right away. The new value doesn't even exist until next render.

```
  function useState(initialState) {
    let hook;
    ...

    let baseState = hook.memoizedState;
    if (hook.queue.pending) {
      let firstUpdate = hook.queue.pending.next;

      do {
        const action = firstUpdate.action;
        baseState = action(baseState);            // setValue HERE
        firstUpdate = firstUpdate.next;
      } while (firstUpdate !== hook.queue.pending);

      hook.queue.pending = null;
    }
    hook.memoizedState = baseState;

    return [baseState, dispatchAction.bind(null, hook.queue)];
  }

function dispatchAction(queue, action) {
  const update = {
    action,
    next: null
  };
  if (queue.pending === null) {
    update.next = update;
  } else {
    update.next = queue.pending.next;
    queue.pending.next = update;
  }
  queue.pending = update;

  isMount = false;
  workInProgressHook = fiber.memoizedState;
  schedule();
}
```

There's also an article explaining the above in the similar way, https://dev.to/adamklein/we-don-t-know-how-react-state-hook-works-1lp8

Answer (score 8):

The **setState** function returned by the **useState** hook in React does not update the state immediately. Instead, it schedules the state update to be processed in the next render cycle. This is because React batches state updates for performance reasons.

If you are trying to access the updated state immediately after calling **setState**, you may not see the updated value right away. Instead, you can use the **useEffect** hook to perform actions after the state has been updated.

Here's an example to demonstrate how you can use useEffect to perform an action after the state update

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This effect will run after each state update
    console.log('Count has been updated:', count);
  }, [count]);

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the above example, the **useEffect** hook is used to log the updated count value after each state update. By passing **[count]** as the dependency array to **useEffect**, the effect will only run when the **count** state changes.

Answer (score 4):

I found this to be good. Instead of defining state (approach 1) as, example,

```
const initialValue = 1;
```

```
const [state,setState] = useState(initialValue)
```

Try this approach (approach 2),

```
const [state = initialValue,setState] = useState()
```

This resolved the rerender issue without using useEffect since we are not concerned with its internal closure approach with this case.

P.S.: If you are concerned with using old state for any use case then useState with useEffect needs to be used since it will need to have that state, so approach 1 shall be used in this situation.

Comment: This answer is not useful. With regard to re-rendering and captured closure values this approach does not make the slightest difference. The only difference it ever makes it when the state value is deliberately set to `undefined`, in this case you will gain the `initialValue` again. Which is just a confusing way of doing it, because you could just set it to the initial value without extra steps.

Comment: Approach 2 pollutes the global space. Approach 1, as mentioned, is an antipattern at best.

Answer (score 2):

If we have to update state only, then a better way can be if we use the push method to do so.

Here is my code. I want to store URLs from [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase) in state.

```
const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState([]);
const [reload, setReload] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (reload === 4) {
        downloadUrl1();
    }
}, [reload]);


const downloadUrl = async () => {
    setImages([]);
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            let url = await storage().ref(urls[i].path).getDownloadURL();
            imageUrl.push(url);
            setImageUrl([...imageUrl]);

            console.log(url, 'check', urls.length, 'length', imageUrl.length);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setReload(4);
    await downloadUrl();
    console.log(imageUrl);
    console.log('post submitted');
};
```

This code works to put URLs in state as an array. This might also work for you.

Comment: `.push` mutates the current state, which is a [bad practice in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980). Here's the proper way to [update a state array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/1218980).

Comment: Calling `setImageUrl` in a loop is another bad practice, which will trigger a new render for each time it was called since it's not batched when called asynchronously (outside React's lifecycle). The proper way would be to build the new array and then call `setImageUrl` only once.

Comment: Also, using [`await` in a loop like that is inefficient](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop). Something like [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would improve this.

Answer (score 1):

### ⚠️ Functional Components

I believe a super clean way would be to create *a custom hook* that provides the ability to pass a callback to the setter function, then it would be a 100% guarantee to do some actions exactly after the update of the state.

By taking a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000280/6877799) you can understand how to make the `useStateCallback` hook. Defining a state by using the `useStateCallback` would be like the following:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useStateCallback(0);

const handleFooBar = () => {
  setCount(c => c + 1, () => { // The callback function
    // All actions here will be run exactly AFTER the update of the count state
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the useEffect hook with a dependency array containing isOpen, the callback function will be executed every time the isOpen state changes, ensuring that console.log(isOpen) logs the updated state value. This way, you can correctly handle state updates and ensure that your UI reflects the current state of your component.

Answer (score 0):

With custom hooks from my library, you can wait for the state values to update:

1. `useAsyncWatcher(...values):watcherFn(peekPrevValue: boolean)=>Promise` - is a promise wrapper around useEffect that can wait for updates and return a new value and possibly a previous one if the optional `peekPrevValue` argument is set to true.

([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-watcher-njuoc?file=/src/TestComponent.js))

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
    import { useAsyncWatcher } from "use-async-effect2";
    
    function TestComponent(props) {
      const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
      const [text, setText] = useState("");
    
      const textWatcher = useAsyncWatcher(text);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setText(`Counter: ${counter}`);
      }, [counter]);
    
      const inc = useCallback(() => {
        (async () => {
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
          setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
          const updatedText = await textWatcher();
          console.log(updatedText);
        })();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div className="component">
          <div className="caption">useAsyncEffect demo</div>
          <div>{counter}</div>
          <button onClick={inc}>Inc counter</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default TestComponent;
```

2. `useAsyncDeepState` is a deep state implementation (similar to this.setState (patchObject)) whose setter can return a promise synchronized with the internal effect. If the setter is called with no arguments, it does not change the state values, but simply subscribes to state updates. In this case, you can get the state value from anywhere inside your component, since function closures are no longer a hindrance.

([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-deep-state-5c9d0?file=/src/TestComponent.js))

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { useAsyncDeepState } from "use-async-effect2";

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useAsyncDeepState({
    counter: 0,
    computedCounter: 0
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(({ counter }) => ({
      computedCounter: counter * 2
    }));
  }, [state.counter]);

  const inc = useCallback(() => {
    (async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      await setState(({ counter }) => ({ counter: counter + 1 }));
      console.log("computedCounter=", state.computedCounter);
    })();
  });

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncDeepState demo</div>
      <div>state.counter : {state.counter}</div>
      <div>state.computedCounter : {state.computedCounter}</div>
      <button onClick={() => inc()}>Inc counter</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var [state,setState]=useState(defaultValue)

useEffect(()=>{
   var updatedState
   setState(currentState=>{    // Do not change the state by get the updated state
      updateState=currentState
      return currentState
   })
   alert(updateState) // the current state.
})
```

Comment: Don't do that. `setState`'s setter callback should be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Also, here, `updatedState` would always be `undefined`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron do you have a link to the documentation stating that the callbacks should be free of side effects?

Comment: I dont have the link on hand, but it's documented alongside strict mode, which helps identify unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

**Without any addtional NPM package**

```js
//...
const BackendPageListing = () => {
    
    const [ myData, setMyData] = useState( {
        id: 1,
        content: "abc"
    })

    const myFunction = ( x ) => {
        
        setPagenateInfo({
        ...myData,
        content: x
        })

        console.log(myData) // not reflecting change immediately

        let myDataNew = {...myData, content: x };
        
        console.log(myDataNew) // Reflecting change immediately

    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={()=>{ myFunction("New Content")} }>Update MyData</button>
        </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

My issue wasn't really trying to access the state right away after calling the set method. I was attempting to do it in a completely different function after the rerender had happened but the update still wasn't being reflected. The target function was defined in a functional component but it was being called from a class component.

In my case, I ended up realizing that it was an issue caused by a stale closure. This was likely happening because class components do not use `useState` functionality and so the class component in my code took the function passed to it and created a copy of it or something and that copy was not using the most up-to-date reference to my variable. Actual variables passed directly to the class component still got reflected properly though.

#### Solution

Replacing the class component with a functional component solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to what @aprillion and @shubham-khatri suggested.

@shubham-khatri suggested this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of movies
}, [movies]);
```

right ?

But my code was like this (`myfunction` being triggered on a click event)

```
const myfunction = useEffect(async () => {
    // action on update of movies
}, [movies]);
```

This above code was still not working. Note the difference, the difference is I have `async`. In case you have `async` the code will not wait for updated `movies` irrespective of `[movies]` , so you will have to do like this:

```
const myfunction = useEffect(async (mymovies) => {
    // action on passed value of mymovies
}, []);
```

and the calling code changed from `onClick={myfunction}` to `onClick={() => myfunction(movies)}`

Answer (score 0):

Since useState is async direct replacement of state is not a good idea. so it is better to access the previous state and set new updated value.

for ex: setState((prev)=>[...prev, ...result]);
//result is array of objects

Answer (score -2):

Not saying to do this, but it isn't hard to do what the OP asked without useEffect.

Use a promise to resolve the new state in the body of the setter function:

```
const getState = <T>(
  setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>
): Promise<T> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setState((currentState: T) => {
      resolve(currentState);
      return currentState;
    });
  });
};
```

And this is how you use it (example shows the comparison between `count` and `outOfSyncCount`/`syncCount` in the UI rendering):

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [outOfSyncCount, setOutOfSyncCount] = useState(0);
  const [syncCount, setSyncCount] = useState(0);

  const handleOnClick = async () => {
    setCount(count + 1);

    // Doesn't work
    setOutOfSyncCount(count);

    // Works
    const newCount = await getState(setCount);
    setSyncCount(newCount);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Count = {count}</h2>
      <h2>Synced count = {syncCount}</h2>
      <h2>Out of sync count = {outOfSyncCount}</h2>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Increment</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: `setState` setter callback should be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: I am in favor of emphasizing pure functions, but that link isn't specific to the `useState` callback (there are use cases for not using a pure function as the callback). Also, although this isn't "pure", it doesn't actually change any state either.

I'm not saying this is the best way (I don't use it), just that it provides an alternative solution to the OPs question

Comment: Using count and or callbacks hinders the design method behind usestate itself I'm afraid.

Comment: Again, not saying this is the best way or to use it, just saying it works. Would be more useful to say what the issues would be in using it with a reproducible example as opposed to disregarding it from a design theory level

Comment: "A design theory level" seems to be a perfectly valid reason to criticize something. Just because something works or is possible doesn't make it worth putting out there. Folks might actually use this pattern in spite of the warnings. There are much better ways to deal with the "problem" (it's not exactly a problem to begin with, just seems like that to folks who are unused to asynchronous code).

Comment: Not disagreeing with you. My point is that no one has given a concrete example or explanation on what the warnings or drawbacks are here, or a link that shows how this is incongruent with the design. I'm fine with the downvotes, but I don't find a comment like "there are much better ways" to be particularly insightful even though it may be perfectly valid, just show it or link to something :)

Answer (score -3):

```
// replace
return <p>hello</p>;
// with
return <p>{JSON.stringify(movies)}</p>;
```

Now you should see, that your code actually **does** work. What does not work is the `console.log(movies)`. This is because `movies` points to the *old state*. If you move your `console.log(movies)` outside of `useEffect`, right above the return, you will see the updated movies object.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is down voted heavily, it goes tell how to get "expected" console.log value by putting it outside useState function. Simple and sweet, if somebody wants to know why it is happening like that can refer to above detailed clarifications

Comment: Good try though

Answer (score -4):

Use the [Background Timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) library. It solved my problem.

```
const timeoutId = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {
    // This will be executed once after 1 seconds
    // even when the application is the background
    console.log('tac');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Adding a delay is not an actual solution.. its just a workaround.. even then, you dont need a library for that when you can just use a simple setTimeout